# Error while saving the dataframe as a table in spark-databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I get the below error while using the command

`df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testDB.someTable")`

However
`df.write.mode("Overwrite").option("path", "abfss://..../testDB.db").saveAsTable("testDB.someTable")`  works.
ie., if the path of the adls is passed, it works fine.

I am setting the `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` in my spark context, and in logs i can see `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` is also rightly pointed to the dir mentioned in `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`.

What is missing here ?

Exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:
Please enter a valid location  )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:862)...............
    Caused by: MetaException(message:
Please enter a valid location  )
```

Comment: which error do you get? Where is the stack trace or error message?

Comment: Added the exception now!